# How to generate multiple HTML items based on a properties file?

Tags: java, jstl, properties-file

I have the following properties file:

```
title = Welcome to Home Page
total = 5
gallery1 = images/gallery/cs.png
text1 =  <b>Counter Strike</b><br />
gallery2 = images/gallery/css.png
text2 =  <b>Counter Strike Source Servers Available</b>
gallery3 = images/gallery/cs.png
text3 =  <b>Counter Strike</b>
gallery4 = images/gallery/cs.png
text4 =  <b>Counter Strike</b>
gallery5 = images/gallery/cs.png
text5 =  <b>Counter Strike</b>
```

I am loading it as follows:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getPropertyMap(String asPropBundle) throws ApplicationException {
    HashMap<String, String> loMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ResourceBundle loRB = (ResourceBundle) moHMProp.get(asPropBundle) ;

    if (loRB == null) {
        throw new ApplicationException("No property bundle loaded with name: " + asPropBundle);
    }

    Enumeration<String> loKeyEnum = loRB.getKeys();

    while (loKeyEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) loKeyEnum.nextElement();
        loMap.put(key, loRB.getString(key));
    }

    return loMap ;
}
```

The returned map is set as HTTP request attribute.

I am generating the HTML in JSP as follows:

```html
<li class="s3sliderImage">
    <img src="${map.gallery1}" />
    <span>${map.text1}</span>
</li>
.
.
.
<li class="s3sliderImage">
    <img src="${map.gallery2}" />
    <span>${map.text2}</span>
</li>
```

How can I do this dynamically in a loop? I have the total amount of records in `total` property of the properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Resource Bundle is already sort of a map from keys to values, except it has a fallback mechanism. Why do you copy its content to another map?

Just use the `<fmt:message>` tag: its goal is precisely to get a message from a resource bundle and to output it to the JSP writer. And it can be parameterized, of course :

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="the.base.name.of.your.Bundle"/>
<fmt:message key="text2"/>
<img src="<fmt:message key="gallery2"/>" />

<fmt:message key="greeting">
  <fmt:param value="${user.firstName}"/>
</fmt:message>
```

This last snippet displaying "Welcome John!" if the value of the greeting key is "Welcome {0}!".

The  tag can also store the value in a variable, and take an EL expression as parameter, so this snippet should work to implement your loop:

```
<fmt:message var="total" key="total"/>
<c:forEach begin="1" end="${total}" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <li class="s3sliderImage">
        <img src="<fmt:message key="gallery${loopStatus.index}"/>" />
        <span><fmt:message key="text${loopStatus.index}"/></span>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Good point, but this is not exactly what the OP *actually* is asking.

Comment: Ah, OK. I missed the last part of the question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @JBNizet getting error ...at at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.handleMissingResource(JspServlet.java:335)

Comment: didnt worked tried a lot of combinations and manipulated it.. :(

Comment: @Varun : I checked some typos in the example (key instead of value in the fmt:message tag, and loopStatus instead of varStatus). I tested this solution, and it works as expected. Show us the whole JSP file, and tell us the complete path of the bundle file in your web app. Make sure to declare the use of the fmt taglib at the top of the JSP.