# Thymeleaf spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Inside My appli.proprety i have some text for example

```
app.test=<p><span class="lettrine">Hello</span>World</p>
```

In my view i try to get it inside a div with thymeleaf like this :

```
<div th:text="#{app.test}"></div>
```

it doesn't working!!

but it work when i write it inside the div :

```
<div><p><span class="lettrine">A</span>Hello</p></div>
```

So what exactly the problem and how i can  fixed it?!
Ps: I have many text inside my data base with html, not working too.

Comment: Refer this..this is for jsp but conecpt may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778925/how-to-generate-multiple-html-items-based-on-a-properties-file

Comment: i have already the solution with jsp..but thanks for  your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `th:utext`instead of `th:text`.

Like this

```
<div th:utext="#{app.test}"></div>
```

Comment: thank you,its work now !!..but what is the difference between th:text and th:utext????

Comment: th:text renders the string as it is while th:utext renders the string with html formatting :). If the answer is helpful please upvote.